# Rendering user specific data

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a webapp which renders data for the user specifically.
I have to models, one for the user (djangos built in User) and one for the data to be rendered.
My model ffor the user:

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My model for the data:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user_k = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='RelatedName',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date_Time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    DataOne = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    DataTwo = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    DataThree = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

In my views.py file i have this view for it:

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    model = models.User
    context_object_name = 'mylist'
    template_name = 'my_app/example.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(user_k=self.request.user)
```

And my problem that i can't solve is that I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot query "user": Must be "MyModel" instance.
```

I've googled it multiple times also tried the django documentation.
My guess is that the problem might be in the my models, where my intention was to connect my second model to the username, but I'm not sure.

**Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason `User` would have a `user_k` attribute so `User.objects.filter(user_k=xxx)` makes no sense.

Either use your `MyModel` model:

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    model = models.MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.filter(user_k=self.request.user)
```

Or use your `UserProfileInfo` model:

```
class MyView(DetailView):
    model = models.UserProfileInfo

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserProfileInfo.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Then I'm getting this error: 'Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: user_k, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions, username'

Comment: Changed it to UserProfileInfo, and now it's: Generic detail view BakteriumListView must be called with either an object pk or a slug. I Know it should my in my urls.py but  in my case thats would not work, I'm not redirecting from another view. How should I change it? Maybe ListView?

Comment: There must be something else going on. If you want the "data" you're talking about, you should use `MyModel`